# Problem with PCSXR emulator after kernel upgrade

Tags: upgrade, updates, games, emulation, pcsx

The emulator worked perfectly before the last kernel update, now it has the following error loading the BIOS, or an ISO or DVD:

Gtk-Message: 13: 30: 31.611: GtkDialog mapped without a parent transient. This is discouraged.
RGB & YUV not found. Quitting.

I reinstalled the program and it continued to present the same error, and erased ALL the files and tried again and the error persists.
I still reinstalled with a clean install the new ubuntu and PCSXR and it continues with the same problems.
Is anyone with the BIONIC BEAVER version and the emulator running normally?
Can someone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Switch the graphic to OpenGL driver.

If you found this error:

`pcsx: ../libpcsxcore/ix86_64/ix86-64.c:158: MEMADDR_OP: Assertion '!isreg || reg != 0' failed.`

or something along the line afterwards (mine was `pcsxr: ../libpcsxcore/ix86_64/ix86-64.c:160: MEMADDR_OP: Assertion !isreg || reg != X86_TEMP' failed.`), edit the file `~/.pcsxr/pcsxr.cfg` and change the line `Cpu = 0` to `Cpu = 1`.

[Source](http://blog.ryanhalliday.com/2018/02/pcsxr-errors.html)